# Error thrown on navigator pop until : "!_debugLocked is not true

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigator

Whenever I run the application at that time homescreen is only shows for a maximum of 5 seconds and without a click, I navigate to another page.
Which second page is product detail page, and on first page, product was displaied by catedories.

````
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ItemCard(
                  product: products[index],
                  press: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                          product: products[index],
                        ),
                      )),
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````

#### Error :

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Assertion failed: file:///C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4842:12
!_debugLocked
is not true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the widget tree has built before navigating you can do that by warpping your function like this

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
     MyPage()));
```

});